# Странные комментарии wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cms, комментарии

Здравствуйте. В wordpress появился странный комментарий(комментарии от неавторизованных пользователей отключены) к статье, вместо логина - заголовок статьи, и естественно такой пользователь не зареган. Сначала думал в wordpress дыра и можно запостить коммент curl-ом, проверил - нет, авторизация всё равно требуется. Есть идеи как такое могло случиться и как от этого защищаться?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: плагином скорее всего каким то

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего это так называемые уведомления и обратные ссылки. Проверьте настройки в Настройки -> Обсуждения. Отключите там пункт "Разрешить оповещения с других блогов (уведомления и обратные ссылки) на новые статьи"

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/92210)

Comment: @Doofy, обоснуйте, пожалуйста

Comment: 'Скорее всего' - не ответ, а рассуждение